# Custom legend labels react-chartjs-2

Tags: react-chartjs, chartjs-2.6.0, react-chartjs-2

I look all over the chartjs documentation and StackOverflow issues but can't find an example of how to custom legend labels in react-chartjs-2.
I want to switch the default labels to checkboxes like the photo: [image]

can someone please help me with that?